# Prove that ABC + ABC' + AB'C + A'BC = AB + AC + BC

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm trying to prove that ABC + ABC' + AB'C + A'BC = AB + AC + BC using Boolean Algebra indentities. Can anyone help? Could you please show the steps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to factorize `A.B + A.B' = A.( B + B' )`. Because `( B + B' )` is always true ( something or not something ), you have `A.true` and this is purely equivalent to `A`. `AND` and `OR` for factorisation and development works the same has addition and multiplication.

This is how you proceed.